# Creating a dictionary from a string of data

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary from a string of data that I pulled from a text file. It is already in the format of a dictionary but it is a string. How can I transfer this data to a dictionary?

Program:

```
f = open('output.txt')
a = f.readlines()
b = [l.strip('\n') for l in a]
print b
```

Data:

```
['12v: 12.1968', '3.3v: 3.312', '5v: 5.04', 'CPU Temp: 33', 'Disk1 Mounted: 1', 'Disk1 Used Space: 32', 'Disk2 Mounted: 1', 'Disk2 Used Space: 0', 'Fan speed: 3245', 'Motherboard Temp: 30', 'VCore: 1.352']
```

What do I need to add to my program?

Comment: Good. Here you go: `dict(x.split(':') if ':' in x else (x, None) for x in b)`.

Comment: The data is not in the format of a Python dictionary though. And not all lines contain a colon either, e.g. `'Disk2 Used Space 0'`.

Comment: Yeah didn't see that, that's a simple fix in another program. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean *"What do I need to add"*? You need to add code to transfer that data to a dictionary.

Comment: Obviously, "what code do I need to add?" was my real question I guess

Comment: In that case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215694/248731

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple code like (not compact though)

```
my_dict = {}
for element in b:
    k,v = element.split(":")
    my_dict[k] = v
my_dict

{'12v': ' 12.1968',
 '3.3v': ' 3.312',
 '5v': ' 5.04',
 'CPU Temp': ' 33',
 'Disk1 Mounted': ' 1',
 'Disk1 Used Space': ' 32',
 'Disk2 Mounted': ' 1',
 'Disk2 Used Space ': ' 0',
 'Fan speed': ' 3245',
 'Motherboard Temp': ' 30',
 'VCore': ' 1.352'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file content is not in python dictionary format. Also there is no colon in `Disk 2 Used Space 0`. If you put colon there, then python dictionary can be created

```
d = {}
for pair in eval(b):
    key, value = pair.split(':')
    d[key] = value.strip()
print d
```

or

```
d = dict([(x.split(':')) for x in eval(b)])
```

Comment: Yeah I fixed the colon problem on Disk 2 Used Space

Answer (score 0):

As a simple comprehension :

```
f = open('output.txt')
a = f.readlines()
b = [l.strip('\n') for l in a]

my_dict = dict( [(line.split(":")) for line in b])
```

Assuming every entry contains a ':' (colon)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work if I understand what your trying to do:

```
f = open("myfile")
dict = {}
fsplit = ""
flines = f.split("\n")

for i in range(len(flines)):
    fsplit = flines[i].split(":")
    dict[fsplit[0] = fsplit[1]
```

Whats happening is its spliting each line into flines, then looping trough all the lines and making a temporary variable that holds a list with to strings split with a colon. After that it just adds the 2 words to the dictionary.

Your file should then look like this and it should work:

```
myword : hello
mynextword : bye
mythirdword : this should work
```